# How to truncate each line for TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have a multiline `TextView`, with a text, for example:

```
Something
Other Something with really big name, that will not fit one line
Another something
Other Something with really big name, that will not fit one line
Other Something with really big name, that will not fit one line
Final something
```

I want to truncate big lines in TextView without moving content to next line, so the out put will be like:

```
Something
Other Something with...
Another something
Other Something with...
Other Something with...
Final something
```

What should I do for that?

Comment: I don't think TextView supports that. You can split your text into different TextViews, and ellipsize each of them.

Comment: why not have multiple textviews added dynamically each with maxlines set to 1 with the ellipsize

Comment: @Kushan for the sake of optimization.

Comment: If you want optimization then go for a recyclerview with holders being textviews.... that should do the trick and solve your issue

Comment: You can write a function to make the string like your expected output.

Comment: @Kushan it is not always the case. You can have big list with different contents. One of them will be small sublist consisting from 3 to 10 really small texts. Using sub-recyclerview and textview for each text for me seems like overhead in that case, but using special span is ok